# Go-to resource for open hardware engineering resources?

Tags: technical-drawing

If you would search for open source software projects, you'd probably run into GitHub and BitBucket.

Is there a similar site/community around open hardware to share *and version* CAD files, curcuits, etc. (not modeling software but an open hardware product oriented)?

Comment: I don't know about CAD files, but for circuits, Altium have a program called CircuitMaker which lots of people contribute to with reference to github for software etc.

Comment: "Finding things" questions like this are off-topic for the site.

Comment: You are looking for open hardware sites, or open hardware platforms

Comment: Most programs have their own specific forums, of some kind.
Solidworks --> Solidworks forum.  Labview --> Labview forum.  etc.

Comment: Yes a version control system for mechanical engineering is called  a product document management system. But the reason you dont find a lot of mechanical hardware designs on open PDM servers is that PDM systems are quite expensive with cost per user (CAD history formats are mostly properitary merging needs that software) But beyond that engineering drawings dont have copyright as such such. Like distributing all code in a MIT like licence without the name or licence keepig right. But there are sites that distribute files like GrabCad also most manufacturers give out their simplified files.

Comment: I would be happy if your question could be reopened, but it is against the rules. However, you might try https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com, where it would be a better match.

Comment: @peterh the question is against the rules as asking for resources is out of scope. If user can drop asking about that part then its fine.

Comment: @peterh thank you though I fail to identify a matching tag in that community.